# Find Sku if planName is given in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet, sku

I am new to `AzureAD` Powershell.

I have some `ServicePlanName` like `Deskless ,SHAREPOINTSTANDARD`, I want the correspondent `SkuID` (here O365PREMIUM's Skuld).

My input will be the `ServicePlanName` and the output should be `SKUID`.
I don't know which command should be used in PowerShell.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please do not repeat the same question that you already asked. Please delete one or the other of them.

Comment: @EBGreen deleted as u said, I forget that I have already asked, sorry for that

Comment: "I forget that I have already asked", That's special :)

Comment: @Avshalom what to do, this much level interest

Comment: show the command you are using, and the results and what you expecting to get...

Comment: @Avshalom `Get-AZureSubscribedSKu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to get the `SkuId` via `ServicePlanName`, please try the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
$licenses = Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Where {$_.ServicePlans.ServicePlanName -eq "yourServicePlanName"}
$licenses.SkuId
```

[image]